# Django-allauth: how does django know which form to use in form.as_p?

Tags: django

I am just learning Django especially using allauth to build a login/signup module.
I am reading the source code of allauth-master/allauth/templates/account/login.html and I came across the line {{ form.as_p }}

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
```

I know the function of "{{ form.as_p }}". But it became confusing as I further looked into allauth-master/allauth/account/forms.py: there are a lot of classes/forms there.

Just want in login.html, how does Django know to use the "LoginForm" rather than other forms?

Comment: Sorry a typo. Just wonder: in login.html, how does Django know to use the "LoginForm" rather than other forms?